# Illegal start of expression in jcreator

Tags: syntax-error

I am not sure why there is an error, which keeps on saying that there is an illegal start of expression and  ')' is expected  error. It occurs in line 14.

```
1 import java.io.*;
2 public class LeapYear{
3 public static void main(String[] args){
4   String leapYear="";
5   int intleapYear;
6   
7   BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(
8       new InputStreamReader(System.in));
9       
10  try{
11      System.out.print("Enter a year: " +leapYear);
12      leapYear=input.readLine();
13      intleapYear=Integer.parseInt(leapYear);
14      boolean isleapyear= ((intleapYear%4==0)&&(intleapYear%100!==0)||(intleapYear%400==0));
16      
17      
18  if(isleapyear){
19      System.out.println(intleapYear + " is a leap year.");           
20  } else
21  System.out.println(intleapYear + " is not a leap year.");
22                     
23  }catch(IOException e){
24      System.out.println("Error");
25  }
26  
27
28      
29  
30  /*if ((intleapYear%4==0)&&(intleapYear%100!==0)||(intleapYear%400==0)){
31          System.out.println(intleapYear+" is a leap year.");
32      }else
33      System.out.println(intleapYear+" is not a leap year.");*/
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are using `!==`

you should use `!=`

so line 14 would be:

```
boolean isleapyear= ((intleapYear%4==0)&&(intleapYear%100!=0)||(intleapYear%400==0));
```